# How to understand requestAnimationFrame callback timing in performance profiler?

Tags: javascript, animation, dom, profiling, requestanimationframe

I'm trying to create an animation using requestAnimationFrame and am struggling to get consistently good frame rates. I figured my frame drawing callback was probably too expensive, so I open up the Firefox performance profiler and I get this stack chart for a short section of playback:

[image]

The stack chart shows calls to FrameRequestCallback (the yellow bars) taking 15-22ms. But in between these calls are long periods of 8-30ms where FrameRequestCallback is not called and instead all we see is something called ZwWaitForAlertByThreadId in the native stack (gray bars between purple bars). As a result, I'm counting about 25-30 FrameRequestCallbacks per second, with inconsistent pacing in between. This results in animation that is passable for my case, but visibly a bit choppy, and I worry about the performance on lower-powered hardware.

My question is just how I should read this output. It looks to me like I'm getting idle times long enough to draw another frame during which my callback is not called, but I realize I may be misreading the stack chart. A few additional things I considered that might help answer the question:

- Is the thread busy doing something else? I tried checking the other processes in the Firefox profiler to see if something else was using that idle time, but nothing seemed to come close to filling the gray gaps in the main thread. Though I'm not sure whether the profiler is showing me everything that thread is doing. Could other tabs be scheduling work in that thread that is throttling the animation? This seems unlikely to me because I have nothing else process intensive running in the background and this pattern is consistent across multiple profiling attempts across two machines.
- Are my frames taking too long to render? Accounting for the short paint operation (green bars) after the frame callback, most of the render operations are taking about 18ms (though some are shorter). Since that is too slow to render 60 FPS (which is my monitor's refresh rate), is requestAnimationFrame waiting a bunch of extra time because my code wasn't ready to draw again after 16ish ms?
- Occasionally there are some very short ~1.5ms calls to FrameRequestCallback right after a successful draw completes. That made me think maybe my callback is failing and immediately returning in some cases, but these short callbacks occur less than half of the time, and in all other cases there does not appear to be another attempt to render another frame for many ms.

Comment: Possibly related: https://bugzil.la/1625204 If so, that would be a bug between the browser's renderer and your GC.

Answer (score 1):

I've dealt with problems like this, where some rendering operations are taking too long. I did it by creating an interrupt that would wait a given delta-t and stop the process and enter a debugger. I would enable the interrupt when the render starts, and disable it when the render ends. That ensures it will only go off on the renders that take too long. Since when it goes off is a random time with respect to what the program is doing, I can see what's making it take too long by showing the various thread stacks at that time.

The problem is usually something to do with memory allocation or freeing or garbage collection, easily fixed by allocating the offending memory block in advance, and not freeing it.